# Remove stuck ethernet cable tab that has gone through the top of the port

Tags: laptop, ethernet, port, dell-latitude

The ethernet cable tab has actually gone through the top of the port, making it impossible to remove the cord without damaging the port/laptop. In the picture, note the metal pieces at the top of the port are UNDER the tab

Zoomed...

[image]

Original...

[image]

Comment: Can you get another pic from a different angle. That one makes it hard to tell, because we don't have perspective. Also... what happens if you undo that screw?

Comment: I've pushed that first shot as far as I dare in Ps & inlined it.

Comment: You mean that the plastic tab is effectively ***inside*** the metal casing?  If so, you need a small precision screwdriver, in the gap above it. In green - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRuak.jpg

Comment: I hope this helps clarify. The tab on the cable (in red) has somehow gone through the top of the port and I cannot pull it through because the gap at the of the port itself (green) is too small. https://i.imgur.com/pSfbj7F.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting what you mean. There's not enough detail in the pic & I don't quite get what you mean by "through the top". A pic from another angle might help - your 2nd pic is really the same viewpoint as the 1st.

Comment: Stick the small precision screwdriver in the gap to right or left and leverage it out by pure force.

Comment: If the plug went in, it fits through the hole.  That plastic tab at the top needs to be compressed against the body of the plug.  That's where the precision screwdriver fits in.  Pry the tab down while gently pulling on the cable.  Try removing the screw in that metal cover plate over the port.

Comment: Just so we eliminate the obvious [& I apologise if it's *too* obvious] - you **do** know that these are intentionally *locking plugs*, yes? You need to squeeze the plastic tab against the plug body for it to release.

Comment: Yes I know the tab needs to be depressed to remove the cord. However, the tab itself seems to have been too wide for the port and I can't remove it. I've found online that this is known issue with Dell Latitude laptops. Thank you